# how to display my hidden submit button below softkeyboard android

Tags: android

I have two `EditText`s and one submit button but when I enter text in the EditText then my submit button hides below the soft keyboard so how to make it above keyboard when the keyboard appears, i.e., The Button should be visible. I have set a background image in the layout and stuck only two TextBoxs and a button on the background image. 
My xml is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/user_id_bg2" >
    <EditText 
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

        android:text="" 
        android:id="@+id/editText1" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Enter Your User Id"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"   
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>
    <EditText 
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:password="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Enter Your Password"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"  
        android:id="@+id/editText2" 
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/buttonimg"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="237dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@drawable/go_button"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: These links can help you: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html http://davidwparker.com/2011/08/30/android-how-to-float-a-row-above-keyboard/

Comment: i set this but not work in manifest file of activity            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">

Comment: can u do modification in my XMl  code for working it good i will be v thankfull to u..

Comment: Try using linearlayout in your relative layout that will push your layout when k/b appears

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763836/set-scroll-on-whole-layout-android